# Has the recent version of subversion dealt with "Access Denied" errors from windows services that monitor the filesystem?

Tags: svn

Does anyone know if this subversion "bug" has been dealt with?

https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/tags/1.6.9/www/faq.html#windows-access-denied

> **I'm getting occasional "Access Denied" errors on Windows. They seem to happen at random. Why?**
>   These appear to be due to the various Windows services that monitor the filesystem for changes (anti-virus software, indexing services, the COM+ Event Notification Service). This is not really a bug in Subversion, which makes it difficult for us to fix. A summary of the current state of the investigation is available here. A workaround that should reduce the incidence rate for most people was implemented in revision 7598; if you have an earlier version, please update to the latest release.

Currently I am experiencing this same behavior in version 1.5.6 when I try and do a SVN switch (I have suspected McAfee as the culprit for a while and when I saw this I feel it validates my suspicions).  I read through the link given but it seems pretty old, so I didn't know if this FAQ was just outdated and the issue has actually be resolved.  Thanks for any help.

Configuration:
SVN 1.5.6
TortoiseSVN 1.5.9 Build 15518
Windows XP SP3 32-bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it depends on the apps you have installed and how you configured them.
For example, you have to configure your virus scanner to exclude all your working copies.
And maybe also exclude the windows search from indexing the working copies.

if you did all that, then there's only this one left:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itprogeneral/thread/df935a52-a0a9-4f67-ac82-bc39e0585148

But that one will be fixed with Win7 SP1.

Comment: Thanks for the information.  Unfortunately I am unable to add any items to my exclusion list (corporate policy).  I could fill out some forms to have this done, but it is very tedious and will more than likely be denied.  I do know that the indexing service is not being used.  One of our developers created a work around for this to call the svn switch command multiple times until the switch succeeds.  Its a bit hacky but it works.